# WooCommerce pass order data into woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta

Tags: wordpress, action, hook, woocommerce

I'm trying to add user_meta upon checkout in WooCommerce. Currently I'm using woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta action to update user meta. I'd like to pass some of the order data itself in as well specifically I'd like to make the order id the value of the meta like so...

```
function woocommerce_add_my_user_meta( $user_id ) {
   global $woocommerce;
   update_user_meta( $user_id, 'purchased', ''.$order->ID.'' );
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'woocommerce_add_my_user_meta');
```

This however is not working. It's just adding a blank purchased user meta.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` hook

```
// Use hook after checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'do-additional-stuff-on-checkout', 10, 2 );
// Things you want to be done when hook is called
function do-additional-stuff-on-checkout( $order_id, $post_values ) {
    // get user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // update
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'purchased', $order_id );
}
```

Comment: Currently this method doesn't pass the $post_values - just the $order_id param.. They can be accessed with `$_POST` though.